# Infinite row model - Auto Row height

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using infinite row model type for few grids and I need the row height to be set based on the cell content(Auto Height). Can you please help me with this.

When I try setting height using node.setRowHeight(height), api.onRowHeightChanged(), the height is not getting set for infinite row model.

Comment: you can use flex properties such as flex-shrink which gives an enough height for item to fit all the childs.

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to work in my grid . Height is increasing but transform value remains as it is. It's not getting updated .